# Why can't my python code take user input?

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, spyder

```
import itertools
play = True
#players=[1,2]
while play:         #as long as players want to keep playing the game
    game=[[0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0]]
    
    game_won= False
    game = game_board(game, flag=True)
    player_choice = itertools.cycle([1,2])
    while not game_won:
        current_player=next(player_choice)
        print(f"Current Player is {current_player}")
        column_choice=int(input("Which column do you want to play at?(0, 1, 2): "))
        row_choice=int(input("Which row do you want to play at?(0,1,2): "))
        game_board(game,current_player,row_choice,column_choice)
```

#game_board(game_map,player=0, row=0, column=0, flag=False) is function definition

[Code snippet and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE4U5.png)
The second printable statement to take user input i.e. "Which row do you want to play at?(0,1,2): " is not getting executed.

Comment: please post your code as formatted text

Comment: did you press enter after typing `1`?

Comment: [Edit] the question, please. Not as a comment

Comment: @Esther, yes I did

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code there, using the `{}` button to format it properly.

Comment: It appears that this is a bug with your terminal/execution environment. There is nothing wrong with the code (or at least nothing that would prevent the second `input` from executing once the first one did)

Comment: @Esther, I am using Sublime Text for Python 3.10